# git push. Password/account locked?

Tags: git, terminal, passwords, locking

this is my first time pushing project into github and git is blocking my password entry??
I entered my password incorrectly on the first try, afterwards I cant reentry my password again, I get the key emoji and then failed authentication message pops up. Not sure whats happening

[lock sign next to password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPBKK.png)

Comment: It just doesn't display your password, that's all. You can still enter it but it doesn't show it.

Comment: I'm using a mac

Comment: That little key symbol just shows you that Terminal, on your mac, is aware that this is a password and therefore it should attempt to be careful to keep it away from key-logging software. Whether it's any good at actually preventing key-loggers from stealing passwords is another question entirely, but at least you know that Terminal has *noticed*.

Comment: It wont let me enter my password. Should I uninstall git and reinstall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*It could be due to Github changing its encryption methods*, or you just entered it wrong. Are you on Mac or Windows? Either way, it won't display the password you enter. For example, if you tried to clone a private repository, it should display the key icon on a Mac. Then, you enter your password and it won't show up, because it doesn't display the characters, how many there were, or anything for security purposes. Therefore, you probably entered an incorrect password, and it's not any software issue.

If it still doesn't work, you could try uninstalling/reinstalling Git or your terminal, but more information is needed to answer the question with system-specific instructions.